# Return True or false inside a method

Tags: java, boolean

Lets say i have a method and i want to do this method to return true or false.I should declare boolean  but i dont know how.Could you help me with this?How can i do it?I pass objects in my methods with the parameteres and each one i use it.I want to use this objects name,surname and money if the money is bigger than 50 will return true and if it is smaller than 100.In another case this method will return false.

```
public static int trueorfalse(String on,String surname,double money,double cost){
if(get.money>50.0 && get.cost<100.0){
System.out.println("Money is"+money);
System.out.println("Name and accepted"+on);
System.out.println("Surname and accepted"+surname);
y=true;
}
else
{
System.out.println("Money is"+money);
System.out.println("Name and denied"+on);
System.out.println("Surname and denied"+surname);
y=false;
}
return y;
}
```

Comment: change public static int to public static boolean. also google how to return from a method... go through a tutorial.

Comment: Your question suggests that you are trying to code without first reading your text book, without understanding the very basics. You will want to correct this, and read those chapters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the return type to `boolean` from `int`. That is,

```
public static int trueorfalse(String on,String surname,double money,double cost)
```

to

```
public static boolean trueorfalse(String on,String surname,double money,double cost)
```

You **could** simplify it a bit, like

```
public static boolean trueorfalse(String on, String surname, 
        double money, double cost) {
    boolean accepted = get.money > 50.0 && get.cost < 100.0;
    String msg = accepted ? "accepted" : "denied";
    System.out.printf("Money is %.2f%n", money);
    System.out.printf("Name and %s %s%n", msg, on);
    System.out.printf("Surname and %s %s%n", msg, surname);
    return accepted;
}
```

Comment: sorry please if you could repeat

Comment: i really :) i was thinking that inside in my method was false :D I dont know why but now i feel to good that it is right.Thanks a lot i appreciated and sorry for my "bad" question it was difficult for me :)